# Grails application Domain is not mapped issue

Tags: hibernate, grails, dns

We have a Grails application that we have been maintaining for over a year. But recently we started getting errors like

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CareAlert is not mapped [from CareAlert p where p.code in (:code)]
    at $Proxy24.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.deerwalk.FrontEndService.getAlertMessage(FrontEndService.groovy:492)
    at com.deerwalk.FrontEndService$getAlertMessage.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.deerwalk.MemberProfileService.getCareAlertData(MemberProfileService.groovy:81)
    at com.deerwalk.MemberProfileService$getCareAlertData.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.deerwalk.MemberSearchController$_closure6.doCall(MemberSearchController.groovy:891)
    at com.deerwalk.MemberSearchController$_closure6.doCall(MemberSearchController.groovy)
    at grails.plugin.springcache.web.GrailsFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(GrailsFragmentCachingFilter.groovy:66)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:86)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter.doFilter(DevModeSanityFilter.groovy:44)
    at com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:270)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:106)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

we are getting this kind of errors in modules that we have not even touched.
The problem seem to arise from where ever we are making a GORM query like

> CareAlert.findAll("from CareAlert p where p.code in (:code) ",
>   [code:code])

(it is not specific to CareAlert domain)
What seems to solve the problem is that if we make a call to any dynamic finders like
`CareAlert.get(1)` or `CareAlert.findAll()` at least once before the query, the problem seems to go away for that Domain.
So for now we have just put a bunch of lines like

> CareAlert.get(1)
>
> Client.get(1)

in the bootstrap.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Comment: Are you using newer versions of dependencies?

Comment: We are using grails 1.3.7 and all the plugins that we are using are quite old as well. We have not added any new plugin nor have we made any changes to the dependencies...